# how to convert an image file from a URL to a format in scikit-learn that can be used to perform a Multivariate Linear Regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to do a simple multivatiate Linear Regressions where one of the features columns are images. I currently have the URL of each image. How do I convert this URL column into a format that scikit learn will understand(a numerical version of a picture)?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv('dtaset.csv')
df.head()

index followers  likes      urls
  0   14928252   132771   https://url1
  1   14928252   57671    https://url2
  2   14928252   161580   https://url3
  3   14928252   60969    https://url4
  4   14928252   375567   https://url5
```

The Feature columns are 'total_followers' and 'urls' and the target column is "likes"

Anyone?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question has an easy part and a hard part.
The easy one is how to read an image from URL. For this you will need OpenCV. If you don't have it (`import cv2` fails), install it, e.g. using `pip install opencv-python`.
Than you can use this function:

```
import cv2
import requests
def readImage(url, color = False):
    with requests.get(url) as r:
        return cv2.imdecode(np.frombuffer(r.content, np.uint8), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR if color else cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
```

And the hard question is what you will do with the images? An image is (usually) a large array of numbers, most probably, you will need to extract some characteristics and features from it in order to use them in a linear regression. But it depends on the nature of your task.

Comment: thanks man.
Maybe I was too naive to believe that if I just converted the images into arrays and use this in a feature column in the model it would actually take in consideration the picture in my model. What I was trying to achieve was to predict the number of likes of a post on instagram. the model would tkae in consideration # of Likes, # of followers and the image. After looking into some info itś just not this easy.... Thanks!